# Unity AndroidSdkVersions.AndroidApiLevel29 is missing

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

The Google Play now requires all apps to target **Android 10**. I am trying to update the Android Target SDK to Android 10 (SDK 29) in **Unity 2018.4**.

I am trying to set it via code.

`PlayerSettings.Android.targetSdkVersion = AndroidSdkVersions.AndroidApiLevel29;`

However, the enum `AndroidSdkVersions` does not have `AndroidApiLevel29`.

In the meanwhile, I can still manually choose Target SDK in Project settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I found out the Unity 2018.4 still can build for Android 10, while it does not have the enum key `AndroidApiLevel29`

The easy fix would be:

`PlayerSettings.Android.targetSdkVersion = (AndroidSdkVersions) 29;`

Note. If you use Google Play Services Resolver (you probably use it). You should update to the latest version because old ones may not work.